# add last row to grouped query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have three table

```
message= ['id','factory_id','user_id','message_text','status','type'];
factory = ['id','name'];
users=['id','name','profile_pic'];
```

messagges.factory_id is foreign key for factory table
messages.user_id is foreign key for user table
I try to make some things like whatsapp homepage
i want to get last of messages for factory, grouped by user and catch the last message_text

my current code is:

```
return Messages::where('factory_id','=',27)
            ->leftjoin('users','users.id','=','messages.user_id')
            ->select('messages.user_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->groupBy('messages.user_id')
            ->with(array('user' => function($query) {
                    $query->select('id','name','profilepic');
                }))
            ->get();
```

but i dont know how i can add last message_text to this query

Comment: You want list of factories and last message sent by any user. Right?

Comment: yes, i want list of factories and last message sent by any user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
return Messages::select(DB::raw('*, max(id) as OrderId'))
            ->orderBy('OrderId', 'DESC')
            ->groupBy('factory_id')
            ->get();
```

It will give you last message for every factory and you can user and factory name using `with(['user', 'factory'])` for that, you will need to define relations in your model like.

In your `Message` model, something like this if you dont have already.

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function factory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Factory::class);
}
```

---

There is another way to get all records ordered by from Messages table and then get unique using collection functions.

You can do something like.

```
return Messages::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get()->unique()->values()->all();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-unique